# NVD3 creating arcs with start and end angle

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I created a d3 visualization @ [Arc Visualization](http://jsfiddle.net/anandsunderraman/08720m1v/2/).

```
    //creating a scale
    var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]).range([-0.5*Math.PI, 0.5*Math.PI]);

    //creating an arc
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
             .innerRadius(50)
             .outerRadius(100)
             .startAngle(-0.5*Math.PI)
             .endAngle(0.5*Math.PI);
    vis.append("path").attr("d", arc).attr("transform", "translate(300,200)");*/
    var width = 600, height = 400;
    var vis = d3.select("#svg_color");
    var data = [[0,60,"#AA8888"], [60,200,"#88BB88"]];
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(50).outerRadius(100).startAngle(function(d) {
        return cScale(d[0]);
    }).endAngle(function(d) {
        return cScale(d[1]);
    });
    vis.selectAll('path')
       .data(data).enter().append('path').attr('d',arc).style('fill', function(d){
        return d[2];
    }).attr("transform", "translate(300,200)");
```

I am not able to find examples or documentation to create something similar using the NVD3 library.

NVD3 has an example to create pie and donut charts @ [Pie and Donut charts example](http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html)

It does not have examples or documentation on using start and end angles.

Does NVD3 have a wrapper for the arc ?

Comment: Am i answer you question already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems here is the sample you are looking for.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/33tx0ux5/)

You can also find it in the example nvd3 provided.

[custom start angle](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/pieChart.html)

[image]

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.key })
    //.y(function(d) { return d.value })
    //.labelThreshold(.08)
    //.showLabels(false)
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .donut(true);
chart.pie
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle/2 -Math.PI/2 })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle/2 -Math.PI/2 });
```

Hope it helps!